# Subsonic 3.0.0.3 Crash

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Running the latest version of SubSonic (3.0.0.3). Retreiving a single record, making one field change and calling .Save results in a null reference exception in the code below:

public void Update(IDataProvider provider){

```
        if(this._dirtyColumns.Count>0)
            _repo.Update(this,provider);
        OnSaved();
   }
```

My code to create this exception is simply:

```
                DAL.MY_QUEUE l_l_itmEngageItem = MY__QUEUE.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == each.id);
                l_l_itmItem.date_submitted = DateTime.Now;
                l_l_itmItem.Update();
```

Anyone have some insight? 2.0 never gave me an issue. Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the exact same scenario. I was able to insert, but not update.

The cause, I found, was that a primary key was not set on the table. Once the primary key was set, I was able to update.

Comment: this fixed my problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't even look like you're retrieving and updating the same item.  You're retrieving into `l_l_itmEngageItem` and then updating a field on `l_l_itmItem`, which you then call Update() on.

I'm guessing that `l_l_itemItem` hasn't been initialized to anything that's actually in the database yet.

Perhaps the problem is your variable naming ;)