# Subsonic activerecord gets an object reference error when updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, subsonic, subsonic3

I can Insert and can read no probs using Subsonic 3.0.0.4.

However when I try to update, I get a runtime error from my generated ActiveRecord.cs on the line of code below

```
   public void Update(IDataProvider provider){


        if(this._dirtyColumns.Count>0){
            _repo.Update(this,provider); //<--EXCEPTION BLOWS UP HERE
            _dirtyColumns.Clear();    
        }
        OnSaved();
   }
```

Heres the error information and the relevant part of the Stack Trace:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=SubSonic.Core
  StackTrace:
       at SubSonic.Extensions.Database.ToUpdateQuery[T](T item, IDataProvider provider)
       at SubSonic.Repository.SubSonicRepository`1.Update(T item, IDataProvider provider)

My Method that calls Update() is a wrapper method that looks like this:

```
    public static void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        person.Update();
    }
```

Anyone got any ideas? I'm using the .net 4.0 framework just in case that throws a spanner into the works....

Comment: Ok, looking on GitHub, the project itself has had plenty of fixes and changes, and the t4 templates have been updated. Anyone know why these fixes and changes haven't been formalised into a release since July 2010?

Comment: Must be something to do with framework 4. Got the latest source and templates from github. Compiled into an updated SubsonicCore.dll and updated my tt files. Had to hack the tt files around to get it to compile. Now it gets the same error when inserting :( Looks like I'm going to have to ditch Subsonic, which is a shame as I did actually like it

Comment: I'm using Subsonic 2.x with .Net 4.0, and no more hacking.  I also modified the framework to support SQL Server TVP's.  Last time I played around with Subsonic 3.x I had some T4 template issues as well, which is why I reverted back to 2.x.

Comment: for anyone who comes across this thread, take a look at this similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166675/subsonic-3-0-0-3-crash. 

Adding a primary key to the table fixed my problem. (DOH!)